# More LINQY-ness (sub-select)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to use LINQ to build a kind of weird query that uses a sub-query.

I'm really looking for distinct records.  Normally, the SQL would look like this:

```
select distinct col1, col2 from foo where col3 = somevalue
```

However, col2 just happens to be a BLOB, so I can't use *distinct*.  So, I think that the next best SQL looks like this:

```
select f1.col1, f1.col2 
from foo f1 where f1.id in 
  (select distinct f2.id from foo f2 where f2.col3 = somevalue
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to "phrase" that second query in LINQ.  Here's what I have so far, and it works, but I'm not sure whether it's optimal:

```
var query = from f in foo
            where f.col3 == somevalue
            select new {id = f.id};

var result = from f in foo
             join q in query on f.id equals q.id
             select new MyType() {col1 = f.col1, col2 = f.col2};
```

That gives me what I want, but according to SQL Manager, the resulting query is about 8% more expensive than my hand-crafted SQL sub-query.  Is there a better way to write that?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do something, but you don't realize you can do it so your asking a question about something else - Were you trying to ask how you can select col1 and col2, but only run distinct from col1? That is possible.

Comment: @Nick: yes, that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var result = from f in foo
             where query.Contains(f.id)
             select new MyType() {col1 = f.col1, col2 = f.col2};
```

Comment: Yours was the most efficient option that I found.  Thanks!